# symmetric (same axis) Heatmap with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to use ggplot2, to create a symmetrical heatmap. The x-axis should show exactly the same labels as the y-axis. unfortunately does the ddply() method affect the order.

The input.csv looks like this:

```
   Names,Peter,Tom,Marc
    Peter,1,6,1
    Tom,2,4,12
    Marc,3,0,21
```

Im using the following code so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr) 
library(reshape2) 
library (scales) 
dat <- read.csv("input.csv")# read input 
dat.m <- melt(dat)# to "melt" the dataset
dat.s <- ddply(dat.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = scale(value)) #pairwise format
file <- ggplot(dat.s, aes(Names,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),legend.position="top")
pdf(file=paste("output",".pdf",sep="")) # write to file
plot(file)
# make plot
dev.off()
```

This results in a plot where the Y-axis (from top-to-bottom) have the labels Marc-Tom-Peter, but the X-Axis have the labels (left-to-right) Marc-Peter-Tom.

Does anyone know, how I can achieve a plot, where the labels for both axis have the same (original) order ? (Peter,Tom,Marc), note that this is just a toy example - the real data has more than 100 labels so it would not help to manually define the pairs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO.  As a first question you've asked, you've done a number of things nicely.  One way to improve this would be to make this reproducible by adding data?  This is an expected part of asking a question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

First create a vector of the names ordered the way you like it:

```
lvls <- as.character(dat$Names)
```

Next order `variable` so it matches `Names`:

```
dat.s$variable <- factor(dat.s$variable, levels = lvls)
```

Now try plotting.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add the `limits` to your scales. Note that the default is from bottom-to-top, so if I understand you correctly, you also have to use `rev` to reverse the order. Here's a possible solution:

```
ggplot(dat.s, aes(Names,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),legend.position="top") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = dat$Names) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(dat$Names))
```